# AJAX Loading Two Combobox With Same Data Issue -- One get loaded and another always empty

Tags: php, ajax, combobox

Basically I want to load two comboboxes with list of countries and the initializePage() was called at body onload.

Following isolated code is copied from one js file. My problem is: One combobox load is correct, but when I called two function together, alway the last called combobox load is performed(in other words alway one combobox loaded instead of two)

I'm new to AJAX, Please Help

```
var xmlHttp;

function initializePage()
{
    displayCountryFrom();
    displayCountryTo();
}


function displayCountryFrom()
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
     {
     alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
     return
     }

    var url="loadCountry.php";
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=CountryFromstateChanged ;

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function displayCountryTo()
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
     {
     alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
     return
     }

    var url="loadCountry.php";
    url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=CountryTostateChanged ;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}



function CountryFromstateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
     { 
        document.getElementById( "countryListFrom").innerHTML= 
                '<option value="0">------Select Coutry1------</option>'+ xmlHttp.responseText;
     } 
}


function CountryTostateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
     { 

        document.getElementById( "countryListTo").innerHTML= 
                '<option value="0">------Select Coutry2------</option>'+ xmlHttp.responseText;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to have different variables for the two requests.
Right now you have only one: `var xmlHttp`. You have to keep in mind, that `displayCountryTo()` won't wait for `displayCountryFrom()` result to be returned from the server before it starts. Therefore it is bad to have them share the request object.

Comment: Thanks very much!! I was too focused on FromstateChanged, I thought it was the problem that's why I had two copy of it. You are right I really need two different variables for the two requests.